# Windows 8.1 DVD - Use it to upgrade an existing Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

As an MSDN subscriber I have pre-release access to Windows 8.1. I am already running Windows 8, so I'd like to update. Is this possible?

It seems the Windows 8.1 installation media actually wants to overwrite my current installed OS which is obviously not something I want.

Comment: Mount the ISO, run the setup.exe and select Upgrade. This should work.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - It requires a Windows 8.1 key if you do it this way

Comment: @Ramhound No it does not, but I did need to reactivate my Windows afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounted the ISO and selected 'Keep files, apps and settings'. Installed great.

Note: I needed to disable the TPM in UEFI, or the computer would freeze when attempting to install 8.1.

Comment: nice to hear that it worked.